# VSTS How do we trigger automated build of one project when there is a checkin in another project

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS I have 2 Git projects (ProjectA,ProjectB). If ProjectA is updated then automated build is triggered. I would also like ProjectB to trigger also after ProjectA. How do I configure this in VSTS?

I check the trigger section but I not Build completion Add option is disabled. Is this the feature I should be using?

Comment: Are they in the same team project or in different team projects?

Comment: same vsts account but different team project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the build system supports chained builds, those builds must reside within the same team project. Team Projects are intended for isolation of unrelated resources with no dependencies. Since you have dependencies between these repos, ideally, they should not be in separate team projects.

Some options:

1. Script it using the [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/queue?view=vsts-rest-4.1).
2. Make a build definition in Team Project A for the repo hosted in Team Project B, then use chained builds.
3. Host your related repos and build/release definitions in the *same* team project.